# Actuator /metrics endpoint does not include http.server.requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

According to the documentation of the spring boot actuator

`Auto-configuration enables the instrumentation of requests handled by Spring MVC. When management.metrics.web.server.auto-time-requests is true, this instrumentation occurs for all requests. Alternatively, when set to false, you can enable instrumentation by adding @Timed`

And
`By default, metrics are generated with the name, http.server.requests`

When I access the /metrics endpoint I am getting

```
{
  "mem": 405105,
  "mem.free": 150352,
  "processors": 8,
  "instance.uptime": 440055,
  "uptime": 455888,
  "systemload.average": 1.904296875,
  "heap.committed": 315392,
  "heap.init": 262144,
  "heap.used": 164015,
  "heap": 4194304,
  "nonheap.committed": 92800,
  "nonheap.init": 4992,
  "nonheap.used": 89714,
  "nonheap": 0,
  "threads.peak": 64,
  "threads.daemon": 43,
  "threads.totalStarted": 95,
  "threads": 46,
  "classes": 12459,
  "classes.loaded": 12459,
  "classes.unloaded": 0,
  "gc.g1_young_generation.count": 12,
  "gc.g1_young_generation.time": 127,
  "gc.g1_old_generation.count": 0,
  "gc.g1_old_generation.time": 0,
  "httpsessions.max": -1,
  "httpsessions.active": 0,
  "datasource.primary.active": 0,
  "datasource.primary.usage": 0.0,
  "gauge.response.example.users": 2.0,
  "counter.status.200.example.users": 5
}
```

So the http.server.requests is not there. The counter.status.200.example kind of shows the requests that go through my application but they are separated per endpoint. I need an overall for the whole application.
I've tried disabling the `management.metrics.web.server.auto-time-requests` and adding `@Timed` to the endpoints, but that did not work as well. The result was the same as the one above.

Does anyone know how I can show the overall requests that are made to the application?
Thank you in advance.

*EDIT

when I add 
`compile('io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:latest.release')`
I get the following error

```
Parameter 0 of method prometheusEndpointFix in PrometheusEndpointConfiguration required a bean of type 'PrometheusEndpoint' that could not be found.
```

Even though the @Bean is there..

```
@Configuration
class PrometheusEndpointConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public PrometheusEndpoint prometheusEndpoint() {
    return new PrometheusEndpoint(CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry);
  }
...
}
```

Comment: This very much looks like the old Spring Boot 1.x actuator metrics. So I assume you are on Spring Boot 1.x, right?

Comment: yes, I am using Spring Boot 1.5.2

Comment: I've also tried with 
`compile 'io.micrometer:micrometer-spring-legacy:latest.release'`
which supports 1.5 and states the same for the http.server.requests metric
https://micrometer.io/docs/ref/spring/1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Micrometer with Spring Boot 1.5 via `micrometer-spring-legacy` the "old" `/metrics` endpoint from the Spring Boot 1.5 Actuator framework will not get replaced with the Micrometer one. In a Spring Boot 1.5 application, the old actuator metrics implementation and Micrometer live totally independant next to each other.

Currently, the only way I know off for easily visualizing the Micrometer collected metrics in this scenario is using Micrometers Prometheus backend by including `micrometer-registry-prometheus` additionally to `micrometer-spring-legacy`. This will - by default - expose the `/prometheus` endpoint and expose the metrics in the Prometheus exposition format.

Of course, you could also roll your own endpoint implementation which mimics the Spring Boot 2 `/actuator/metrics` endpoint which queries the `MeterRegistry` and visualizes all contained metrics. But even then, this should be merely used for debugging things instead of permanently reading this endpoint and persisting that data somewhere in a metrics store. The Prometheus exposition format has been "developed" for that exact usecase. (And it's quite readable, so can serve as a first look entrypoint in case you are not scraping these metrics.)

Comment: I edited my question adding the suggestion you made.

Comment: @PPetkov You must not use/add any extra Prometheus-Java specific libraries like  `simpleclient_spring_boot`. Everything required is provided with the two Micrometer dependencies I mentioned.

Comment: I indeed had the `simpleclient_spring_boot` library in my project. Removing it fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: What are the two endpoints in this case? I know '/metrics' is one from Spring Actuator, which endpoint should I go for micrometer metrics?

Comment: @San as I had written in the answer, with Spring Boo 1.5 the only actuator endpoint which can be provided by Micrometer is adding `micrometer-registry-prometheus` which will expose the `/prometheus` endpoint. All other Micrometer backend implementations don't offer such a method because they operate push-based and thus don't need to be scraped at the application level, but are rather pushed by the application to the respective metrics store.

Comment: Does it really shows the api response times for each request?

Answer (score 4):

One catch with it is when using the actuators and following the guide of [spring boot 2.2.6](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-features.html) I noticed the *http.server.requests* will not be shown in the metrics list, if no requests have happen so far. After making the first REST request, the http metric becomes available.